# Não consigo clonar um projeto pelo Git e Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, git

Quando eu tento clonar um projeto por dentro do Visual Studio 2017(Enterprise e Community - tentei os dois), tenho esse erro:

> Git process failed unexpectedly. CloneCommand.ExecuteClone

Acho que pode ser minha máquina, mas não sei responder ao certo.

Comment: Minha sugestão é ir pela linha de comando. Normalmente ela é mais confiável e exibe erros mais significativos

Comment: Fiz e não deu mais erro, mas continuo não subindo para o remoto. Fica tudo local. Vou abrir outro post para isso. @JeffersonQuesado, creio que deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro [parece ser um bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html?childToView=27693#comment-27693) de uma versão do Visual Studio.

Tente as seguintes opções:

- Atualizar seu Visual Studio.
- [Desinstalar](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html?childToView=272625#comment-272625) sua versão do Git, remover o Visual Studio via Visual Studio Seteup, instalar a versão mais recente do Git e reinstalar o Visual Studio.
- Como sugerido pelo Jefferson, fazer o clone do repositório por linha de comando ou usando outra ferramenta.

Se nada disto funcionar, recomendo ler a [seguinte thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html?childToView=272625#comment-272625), pois a causa deste problema parece ser **bem** variada e as soluções bem diferentes. Todas aparentemente relacionadas a problemas de configuração do próprio Visual Studio.